# Отключение Drag-n-Drop в dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, vue.js

Перечитал кучу всего. на офф сайте просто советуют `.disable()`. Но я уже все что мог перепробовал, как-то не выходит. в идеале выключать как-то через data-disabled="true" ну или хотя бы как-то. Vue, JQ, ванильно. все подойдет, главное чтоб с консоли нельзя было разблокировать

Comment: Добавьте пример, чтобы понять как вы инициализируете всё это дело, где применяете `disable()`.

Comment: Никак у меня не получается, инициализировал и через опции скриптом и пробовал через дата атрибут. Никак не могу выключить. Задача, при флаге реадонли выключать возможность загрузки файлов

Comment: Добавьте хоть какой то пример, видимо вам не сильно нужен ответ на вопрос... Вы думаете все наизусть знают эти ваши Dropzone всякие, и прочие велосипеды? Нужно видеть как вы подключаете, используете и тд

Comment: я обращаюсь к тем кто хоть раз пользовался этим пакетом, докой я тоже умею пользоваться)

Comment: data-disabled="true" чем не пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можете попробовать добавить следующий css к главному контейнеру с Drag&Drop

```js
let isReadonly = true;
const dropzone = document.querySelector(".drop-zone");

if(isReadonly) {
  dropzone.classList.add("stop-uploading");
}
```

```css
.stop-uploading {
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Остановка загрузки</h1>
  <form class="drop-zone">
    <input type="file" multiple>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` да, спасает, я как-то не подумал. Хотелось бы все же отключить эвенты не только через стили. Но как вариант ответа подходит

Comment: @AndreyIvasko есть очень хорошая фраза "если можете что-то сделать без жс - делайте без жс!"

Comment: @AndreyIvasko нет особого смысла отключать эвенты, все равно при клике из-за pointer-events: none они не срабатывают, а если вы решите остановить их, то вам потом придется заново их включать в дальнейшем, к тому же в случае слушателя события в виде addEventListener, то не зная функцию в качестве 2 аргумента сделать это будет проблематично. Но когда функция известна, то попробуйте использовать что-то из этого:
el.removeEventListener("mousedown", fn);
window.removeEventListener("mousemove", fn);
где fn- функция реализующая drag & drop

Comment: Частично решился вопрос, поэтому подтвердил конкурса. Не особо лучший вариант, но так как их мало - этот самый лучший

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;"
```

---

Пример фейкового кода:

```
<div ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
```

Или:

```
<input id="upload" type="file" ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;" />
```

Comment: увы, такой способ не сработал